# Excel VBA Range Merge Cells and offset

Tags: excel, vba

This can be copied and pasted directly into excel module and run

The issue is in the AddCalendarMonthHeader() 
The month cell should be merged, centered, and style but it is not.  My only thought is the range.offset() in Main() is affecting it but I dont know why or how to fix it.

[image]

```
Public Sub Main()

    'Remove existing worksheets
    Call RemoveExistingSheets

    'Add new worksheets with specified names
    Dim arrWsNames() As String
    arrWsNames = Split("BDaily,BSaturday", ",")
    For Each wsName In arrWsNames
        AddSheet (wsName)
    Next wsName

    'Format worksheets columns
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "How-To" Then
            Call ColWidth(ws)
        End If
    Next ws

    'Insert worksheet header
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "How-To" Then
            Call AddSheetHeaders(ws, 2013)
        End If
    Next ws

    'Insert calendars
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "How-To" Then
            Call AddCalendars(ws, 2013)
        End If
    Next ws


End Sub











Public Sub AddCalendars(ByVal ws As Worksheet, year As Integer)
    Dim startCol As Integer, startRow As Integer

    Dim month1 As Integer, month2 As Integer
    month1 = 1
    month2 = 2
        Dim date1 As Date
        Dim range As range
        Dim rowOffset As Integer, colOffset As Integer

        Set range = ws.range("B1:H1")

    'Loop through all months
    For i = 1 To 12 Step 2
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0)
        date1 = DateSerial(year, i, 1)

        'Add month header
        Call AddCalendarMonthHeader(monthName(i), range)

        'Add weekdays header
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0)
        Call AddCalendarWeekdaysHeader(ws, range)

        'Loop through all days in the month
        'Add days to calendar '        For j = 1 To DaysInMonth(date1)

        Dim isFirstWeek As Boolean: isFirstWeek = True
        Dim firstWeekOffset As Integer: firstWeekOffset = Weekday(DateSerial(year, i, 1))

        For j = 1 To 6 'Weeks in month
            Set range = range.Offset(1, 0)
            range.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Week " & j
            For k = 1 To 7 'Days in week
                If isFirstWeek Then
                    isFirstWeek = False
                    k = Weekday(DateSerial(year, i, 1))
                End If
            Next k
'Exit For 'k
        Next j
'Exit For 'j
'Exit For 'i
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
Public Sub AddCalendarMonthHeader(month As String, range As range)
    With range
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
'       .Interior.ColorIndex = 34
        .Style = "40% - Accent1"
        '.Cells(1, 1).Font = 10
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Value = month
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub AddCalendarWeekdaysHeader(ws As Worksheet, range As range)
    For i = 1 To 7
        Select Case i
            Case 1, 7
                range.Cells(1, i).Value = "S"
            Case 2
                range.Cells(1, i).Value = "M"
            Case 3, 5
                range.Cells(1, i).Value = "T"
            Case 4
                range.Cells(1, i).Value = "W"
            Case 6
                range.Cells(1, i).Value = "F"
        End Select
        range.Cells(1, i).Style = "40% - Accent1"
    Next i
End Sub
Public Function DaysInMonth(date1 As Date) As Integer
    DaysInMonth = CInt(DateSerial(year(date1), month(date1) + 1, 1) - DateSerial(year(date1), month(date1), 1))
End Function








'Remove all sheets but the how-to sheet
Public Sub RemoveExistingSheets()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo Error:
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.name <> "How-To" Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws

Error:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
'Add a new sheet to end with given name
Public Sub AddSheet(name As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)).name = name
End Sub
'Set sheet column widths
Public Sub ColWidth(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo Error:
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 26
           ws.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 4.43
        Next i
Error:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Sub AddSheetHeaders(ByVal ws As Worksheet, year As Integer)
    Dim range As range
    Set range = ws.range("B1", "P1")
    With range
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.ColorIndex = 11
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 26

        .Value = year
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thou shalt burn in hell for merging cells. Seriously. Use the "center on multiple columns" format property instead which will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur you have just saved me from a fiery demise. Seriously, I can't believe I've been wasting my time with merged cells!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are having is that after the first range is merged, the length of the range becomes one column on offsetting. So after that, the next ranges are messed up.

```
    For i = 1 To 12 Step 2
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0) ' Range is 7 columns wide

        date1 = DateSerial(year, i, 1)

        'Add month header
        Call AddCalendarMonthHeader(MonthName(i), range) ' We merge and range is now 1 column

        'Add weekdays header
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0) ' Fix here to make it 7 columns
.
.
.
```

To Fix this, all you need to do is change the size of the range before adding the weekdays header

```
'Add weekdays header
Set range = range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 7)
```

[image]

Comment: That is excellent - I aprpeciate it as it does work.  Ive read several places that merge also causes a lot of issues, mine seems unrelated - do you have any thoughts about using something like HorizontalAlignment to just have the text spread across the row instead of merging?

Comment: I personally feel merging is not as bad as people put it out to be. Just be careful of what you do with the `Range` after it is merged. Things like Offsetting will work in a not so "natural" manner. The thing is that we assume Range to keep its length constant when doing something like an offset, however, that is not so.

Answer (score 3):

Woah, I'm really surprised this works at all! `Range` is a keyword in VBA and Excel, so it is very surprising to me you are able to use that as a variable name without problems.

You can troubleshoot problems like this a lot easier by adding a debug statement:

```
        'Add month header
        Debug.Print "Range Address: " & range.Address & vbTab & "i:" & i
        Call AddCalendarMonthHeader(MonthName(i), range)
        Debug.Print "Range updated00: " & range.Address
        
        'Add weekdays header
        Debug.Print "Range updated0: " & range.Address
        Set range = range.Offset(1, 0) `<---- this is the line where the Offset loses the entire row
        Debug.Print "Range updated1: " & range.Address
```

This results in the following:

```
Range Address: $B$2:$H$2    i:1
Range updated00: $B$2:$H$2
Range updated0: $B$2:$H$2
Range updated1: $B$3
```

So after the second offset, your `range` variable is only a single cell, which means it cannot be merged. Interestingly this is the case even if your `range` variable is renamed.

Now, this behavior ONLY occurs when the `.Merge` function from your method `AddCalendarMonthHeader` is invoked (commenting this out shows your range addresses are accurate for each iteration).

It seems this is directly caused by using `.Merge` - a fair bit of messing around on my part indicates even the following code will *still* have the same problem (note: I renamed your `range` variable to `mrange`):

```
        Debug.Print "Range updated First: " & mrange.Address
        Set mrange = mrange.Offset(1, 0)
        date1 = DateSerial(year, i, 1)
        
        'Add month header
        Debug.Print "Range Address: " & mrange.Address & vbTab & "i:" & i
        Dim mStr As String
        mStr = mrange.Address
        AddCalendarMonthHeader MonthName(i), mrange
        Debug.Print "Range updated00: " & mrange.Address
        
        'Add weekdays header
        Debug.Print "Range updated0: " & mrange.Address
        Set mrange = range(mStr)
        Set mrange = mrange.Offset(1, 0)
        Debug.Print "Range updated1: " & mrange.Address
```

---

### TL;DR

Using `.Merge` causes abnormal functionality with VBA when using `.Offset`. I would recommend trying to modify your code to not use merge, perhaps as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731252/excel-vba-range-merge-cells-and-offset#comment27604338_18731252) says or some other formatting strategy.

Comment: Hi enderland - yeah I was surprised I could use range as it is a keyword as well.  I was also trying to debug.print range.Range thanks for clarifying range.Address.  Im going to give manimatters thought of using .Resize(1,7) for the merge.  I might also consider something other than merge.  I know there is a center across selection which I googled for but couldnt find out how to set the range.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter or xlDistributed - i couldnt really test since my range was being lost from the offset

Comment: @Kairan this problem is actually fascinating to me. When I was messing around with this last night, I could not find any explanation whatsoever as to *why* `.Merge` randomly causes `.Offset` to behave differently, even after using it on a different range entirely.