# Correct syntax for Offset and merged cells - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge, range, offset

I am having trouble with the correct syntax for using offset with merged cells. For example, in column A, row 2 to 5 (A2:A5) is a merged cell. I'm wanting to use offset to get the range of the column over (B2:B5) including the merged cell value so (A2:B5). From there, I am wanting to use that offset range as values for a clustered-column chart. The code I have now only gets the first cell value (B2) but not (A2:B5). Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Trend")
Dim LastRow As Long, partnum As String, findpart As Range
Dim lastrowmerge As Long, FirstRow As Long

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
partnum = TextBox1.Value

' Searches for number in column A including merged cells
If Not Application.IsNA(Application.Match(partnum, Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        Set findpart = Cells(Application.Match(partnum, Range("A:A"), 0), 1)

' If number found , get range values to the right of number found in column A
        Dim xVals As Long
        Set mymergedrange = findpart.MergeArea
'        FirstRow = mymergedrange.Row
'        lastrowmerge = mymergedrange.Row + mymergedrange.Rows.Count - 1

         xVals = mymergedrange.Offset(0, 1) ' (B2 not B2:B5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Range Merge Cells and offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731252/excel-vba-range-merge-cells-and-offset)

Comment: @chrisneilsen `xVals` being a `Long` is a problem too, but `Offset` of a `MergeArea` is indeed a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to a merged area of cells as only the **top-left cell**.

For example, if `A2:A5` is merged, refer to is as if it's only `A2`.

Same goes for offsetting, however merged cells can cause confusion in a number of ways and should generally be avoided with cells containing values.  Merging is generally used only for labels/headings.

If you *must* use merged cells, you can determine the dimensions of the merged area with properties like this example:

```
Sub mergeTest()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

    With r
        If Not r.MergeCells Then
            MsgBox .Address & " is not part of merged cells."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'cell is merged
        MsgBox .Address & " is part of a merged set of " & _
              .MergeArea.Cells.Count & " cells." & vbLf & _
            "It is " & .MergeArea.Columns.Count & " columns tall by " & _
              .MergeArea.Columns.Count & " rows wide." & vbLf & _
            "The address of the merged range is: " & .MergeArea.Address

    End With

End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow: [Detect merged cells in VBA Excel with MergeArea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22076713/8112776)
- Stack Overflow: [Excel VBA Range Merge Cells and offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18731850/8112776)
- PowerSheets: [Excel VBA Merge Cells](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-merge-cells/) *(Caution - lots of ads)*
- MSDN: [MergeArea Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-mergearea-property-excel)
- MSDN: [Range.MergeCells Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-mergecells-property-excel)